# writing script in vf page

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, apex

there is a req where 'lookup' window have to open automatically when page loads, so I used the below code. It is working fine in Chrome and firefox but not in IE.

Here is the vf page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" id="page">
<script type='text/javascript'>
   window.onload=function() { 
      var l = document.getElementById('page:form1:acc_lkwgt'); 
      // document.getElementById('page:form1:acc_lkwgt').click(); 
      l.click(); 
   }
</script>
```

Comment: my full vf code:                                            <apex:page standardController="Contact" id="page">

    <apex:form id="form1">
    <apex:inputField value="{!Contact.AccountId}" id="acc"/>
    </apex:form>
  
    <script type='text/javascript'>
window.onload=function()
{

 var l = document.getElementById('page:form1:acc_lkwgt');

 l.click();
  }
      </script>
</apex:page>

Answer (score 0):

The problem that window.onload javascript is working in different way in IE.
Instead of this you should either use jQuery, or rewrite script in such way:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function doLoad() {
      var l = document.getElementById('page:form1:acc_lkwgt'); 
      l.click(); 
  }
  if ( window.addEventListener ) { 
     window.addEventListener( "load", doLoad, false );
  }
  else 
     if ( window.attachEvent ) { 
        window.attachEvent( "onload", doLoad );
  } else 
        if ( window.onLoad ) {
           window.onload = doLoad;
  }
  </script>
```